# Uninstall is not working when multiple version Installed for MSI application

Tags: visual-studio-2008, uninstallation, windows-installer

I have installed multiple version of MSI(Web Setup Project) applcation.
If I uninstalled any version of MSI, **Uninstall()** function is not calling properly.
Its working only when there is single version of MSI application.

**For Example :**

Version 1, with different Product code.
Installation Path: C:\ ..

Version 2, with different Product code.
Installation Path: D:\ ..

While Uninstalling any version, its not removing folder files properly in that path. (i.e.) Uninstall() function is not called. Even I have set alert message box in Uninstall() function its doesn't call when multiple versions Installed.

Its showing alert message only when single version is Installed.

Comment: Sounds like a component rule violation to me.  Have you logged the uninstall and reviewed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found out the solution at last, by upgrading the product code for each msi version, Uninstall function removing folder files properly in case of multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that this is a managed code custom action being called at uninstall time.

There's no such thing as an uninstall custom action, just a condition that says when it should be called. The condition on managed code "uninstall" custom actions in Visual Studio is something like $C__B24261958FB74C489482DD25851942F5=2 which means to call it when the component is being uninstalled. Anyway, the component isn't being removed because there are other MSIs installed with the same component ids, which is what Chris is getting at I assume. The component is shared with those other products, it's why multiple installs can install the same file to the same location and one uninstall won't remove it.

As I said, you can't control component ids or uninstall conditions in a VS setup. It's not clear what the solution might be because I don't know what your goal is - you seem to be installing basically the same setup again and again, but the files must be the same.

Comment: Hi Phil, There is a misunderstanding, we are not installing at the same location, First version Installation Path considered as ** C:\.. ** Second version is installed in ** D:\.. ** . In Add/Remove Programs there are two versions of msi Uninstaller. As I mentioned above 'While Uninstalling any version, its not removing folder files properly in that path. (i.e.) Uninstall() function is not called. Even I have set alert message box in Uninstall() function its doesn't call when multiple versions Installed.

Its showing alert message only when single version is Installed.'

Comment: You'll need to clarify your issue better. You haven't explicitly confirmed that "Uninstall() function" means an uninstall custom action. It's also not clear why files and folders aren't being removed because custom actions are nothing to do with getting files removed - your MSI will uninstall all the files that it installed. If Uninstall is a custom action, and it is managed code (and you haven't confirmed that either) then where is that assembly being installed to?